# How to send -d flag from curl with Guzzle

Tags: json, curl, guzzle, opencpu

I have the following cURL statement

```
curl http://localhost/ocpu/library/stats/R/t.test -d "x=x0e48e4cb3f&y=x09aaf63ea6"
```

When I run this in the terminal everything is fine and I get the response I want, a completed calculation.

Now I'm trying to build this into a PHP application with the use of Guzzle. I have the following code.

```
$result = $this->client->request('POST', 'http://localhost/ocpu/library/stats/R/t.test', ['json'   => ["x" => $x, "y" => $y],
                                 'header' => ["content" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]])->getBody();
```

$x and $y contain strings with the values of x and y in the cURL statement.

This gives me the error "`400 Bad Request` response:
not enough 'x' observations"

Using the OpenCPU API Explorer I've figured out that I get the same error when trying to add the x and y parameters as primitive strings by adding quotes around them.

So my problem seems to be that Guzzle sends the x and y parameters as strings instead of Temp keys.

How can I get it to send the exact cURL paramater?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$params = [
    'x' => 'value',
    'y' => 'value',
];

$response = $client->post($uri, [
    'form_params' => $params,
]);
```

I believe the issue is within the code sample that you have supplied.  You are using 'json' when 'form_params' is (what i interpret) you are looking for.  When 'form_params' is used, content-type headers are automatically set for form data.

More information can be found within [Guzzle 6 Request Options](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#form-params)

Comment: I think that's about the only option I forgot to try, but it works. Thanks.